# How can I disable the red X button in unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I just want to know how to disable the red X button in the game window using unity, to prevent the player for example from closing the game.

So if anyone knows how to do it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably you started by searching for "unity disable close button" and found [existing answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173596/3064164)? How have you tried applying this to your situation so far?

Comment: Yes! But I don't want to make a confirmation dialog. I want to prevent him completely (I know I can't prevent him completely, but just saying) from closing the game.

Comment: Notice that the engine doesn't know whether you displayed a confirmation dialog. It's just asking you for permission to quit, and you can say "no". It's generally good user experience if that "no" is collected from the player, but there's no mechanism to enforce that if you have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I see. But what if I want to hide the red windows X button to make a splash screen for example?

Comment: Again, you searched for "unity hide title bar" and tried implementing [existing answers](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-how-to-remove-the-title-bar-of-a-game.729437/), right?

Comment: And what should I do? Are there any other alternative solutions?

Comment: Is the one linked in my previous comment (or others you found in your own searches) not working for your needs? If so, you should edit your question to show what you tried and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Actually I didn't find the second link you mentioned. I'll try this.